# how to shift characters to left or right for this specific case? a unique algorithm(fix my algorithm please)

Tags: java, algorithm

Sorry about my English i did my best.

I have this keyCode : "M O N C L E T A B D F G H I J K P Q R S U V W X Y Z"

And this message : "Fish are birds without wings and birds are fish without fins"

overall my program  encodes the message to be grouped by pairs of twos and the new message is "FISHXAREXBIRDSXWITHOUTXWINGSXANDXBIRDSXAREXFISHXWITHOUTXFINS"

so basically each two letters are an array, like "FI" is message[0]; and so on...

spaces are replaced with "X"

problem at my code is I'm trying to figure out the the index of each letter in  pair of twos in the message and then from there the second character from each pair of twos is always shifted to the right mate and the first character is always shifted to the left mate

so if i have FI, I should be translated to the right mate of it ("I" in the keyCode) and F should be translated to the left mate of it( "F" in the keyCode)"

overall I should end up from "FI" to "JD" and so on for the rest of the encoded message

this is also the tricky part of it ,Z has also right mate which is "M and "M has a left made of "Z"

Edit: if it doesn't make sense, basically all i want is to shift the characters of the message to the right or left based on the keyCode rule.

Edit2: posted my actual code.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
class pairwiseCipher
{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("");
    char[] keyCode;              
    keyCode = key();



    System.out.println("");


    String[] message;
    message = message();
    System.out.println(message);








    String encodedMessage;
    encodedMessage = encodedMessage(message,keyCode);
  }


  public static char[] key(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a key in order to perform the opertation.");
    char[] key = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    System.out.print("Keycode with alphabet: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length ; i++){
      System.out.printf("%2c",key[i]);
    }

    char[] alphabet ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i<alphabet.length ; i++){

      System.out.printf("%2s",alphabet[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");



    char[] keyTotalLength = new char[key.length + alphabet.length];
    int index = 0;
    // Add all unique chars from firstString
    for (char c : key) {
      if (! contains(keyTotalLength, index, c)) {
        keyTotalLength[index++] = c;
      }
    }
    // Add all unique chars from secondString
    for (char c : alphabet) {
      if (! contains(keyTotalLength, index, c)) {
        keyTotalLength[index++] = c;
      }
    }

    char[] finalCode = new char[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      finalCode[i] = keyTotalLength[i];
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Scrambled Keycode: ");
    System.out.println(finalCode);
    return finalCode; //This is the Scrambled keycode
  }
  public static boolean contains(char[] in, int index, char t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      if (in[i] == t) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }










  public static String[] message(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a message in order to perform the opertation.");
    String message = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    message = message.replaceAll("X","ks");
    message = message.replaceAll(" ","X");
    String[] fixedMessage = message.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
    System.out.print("The encoded Message:");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < fixedMessage.length ; i++){

      System.out.print(fixedMessage[i]);
      System.out.print(" ");



    }
    System.out.println("------------");
    System.out.println(fixedMessage[0]);
    System.out.println(fixedMessage[0].charAt(1));
    return fixedMessage;

  }



  // This method encodes the given text string using a Caesar
// cipher, shifting each letter by the rule "M O N C L E T A B D F G H I J K P Q R S U V WX Y Z"
public static void encode(String[] text, char[] shift) {
    System.out.print("The encoded message: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        char letter = text.charAt(i);

        // shift only letters (leave other characters alone)
        if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
            letter = (char) (letter + shift);

            // may need to wrap around
            if (letter > 'z') {
                letter = (char) (letter - 26);
            } else if (letter < 'a') {
                letter = (char) (letter + 26);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(letter);
    }
    System.out.println();
}





















}
```

Comment: it's very hard to understand your question.  Try to describe what you are doing in a more succinct way

Comment: Okay basically I'm making a program that recieves a message and a secret key, the key I get will encode the message received based on shifting the message by making each the string of the message pair of twos, and in the pair of twos, the first character is always shifted to left and the second character in that pair is always shifted to the right

Comment: Please tell me if what im asking makes sense? sorry about my english

Comment: You description of the encoding scheme is utterly confusing and contradictory to me. One one hand you describe modifying each letter, depending on its position, then completly unrelatable you talk about "according to key code". You also do not mention how edge cases, e.g. spaces are incorporated into the character derivation, nor do you define what happens when the message length is an odd number of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are probably trying to do!!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class pairwiseCipher{
  public static void main(String[] args){

      char[] key= {'M', 'O', 'N', 'C', 'L', 'E', 'T', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'U','V', 'W','X','Y','Z'};
      char[] old = null;
      char[][] neww = null;
      char[][] ans = null;
      String msg= "Fish are birds without wings and birds are fish without fins";
      msg = msg.toUpperCase();

      msg = msg.replace(' ', 'X');
      System.out.println(msg);
      old = msg.toCharArray();
      neww = new char[msg.length()/2][2];
      ans = new char[msg.length()/2][2];
      for(int i=0,j=0; i<msg.length() ; i=i+2,j+=1){
          neww [j][0] = old[i];
          neww [j][1] = old[i+1];
      }

      //this is just to display characters in pairs
      for(int j=0; j<neww.length; j++){
          System.out.print(neww[j][0]+""+neww[j][1] + " ");
      }

      System.out.println();
      List<Character> cList = new ArrayList<Character>();
      for(char c : key) {
          cList.add(c);
      }

      for(int j=0; j<neww.length; j++){

          int x = (cList.indexOf(neww[j][1]) + 1 ) == 26 ? 0 : (cList.indexOf(neww[j][1]) + 1 );
          int y = (cList.indexOf(neww[j][0]) - 1 ) == -1 ? 25 : (cList.indexOf(neww[j][0]) - 1 );

         ans[j][0] = cList.get(x);
         ans[j][1] = cList.get(y);
      }

      for(int j=0; j<ans.length; j++){
          System.out.print(ans[j][0]+""+ans[j][1] + " ");
      }
      //System.out.println(cList.get(0));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get started...!!

```
public class Encrypter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //you can take key as a space separaed string and split it into array of chars 
        char[] key= {'M', 'O', 'N', 'C', 'L', 'E', 'T', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'U','V', 'W','X','Y','Z'};
        char[] old = null;
        char[][] neww = null;
        String msg= "Fish are birds without wings and birds are fish without fins";

        msg = msg.replace(' ', 'X');
        System.out.println(msg);
        old = msg.toCharArray();
        neww = new char[msg.length()/2][2];
        for(int i=0; i<msg.length()/2 ; i=i+2){
            {
                neww [i][0] = old[i];
                neww [i][1] = old[i+1];
            }
        }
        //this is just to display characters in pairs
        for(int j=0; j<neww.length; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
                System.out.print(neww[j][k]+" ");
            }   
        }

        //Now you can write the code that replaces proper character in the message from key 
        //....
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time but, I'm not sure if that follows the rule where you shift the message characters by the key ?

Comment: Basically  substitute each letter of the pairs(message) by the following rule,
using the left and right mates in: M O N C L E T A B D F G H I J K P Q R S U V WX Y Z
Translating F I : take the right mate of I ( J ) , followed by the left mate of F ( D ) : J D
Translating S H : take the right mate of H ( I ) , followed by the left mate of S ( R ) : I R
Translating XA: take the right mate of A (B), followed by the left mate of X (W): BW
and so on.... does this make sense?

Comment: Dear @Davidmark ..Yes, it totally made sense how you want to get the final encrypted message. But the logic that I provided was just to get pairs of two characters. I haven't included the logic for replacing `left and right mates` .. I just provided the ice breaker code because at that time you didn't posted your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a left Map and a right Map using java.util.HashMap.  Then, for each character pair, you could just output rightMap.get(char2) + leftMap.get(char1).

Comment: I dont understand that syntax, is it possible to do it by indexOf? or charAt() ?

Comment: Yes.  You can use indexOf to search the position of each character from your sentence within your key.  Add or subtract 1 from that position depending on whether you're on an odd or even character.  If your new position=-1, set to 25, if it's 26, set to 0.  Then, use key.charAt(pos) to return the encrypted character.